# EntityFramework 7 Error when adding entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error when trying to add a new entity to an Entity Framework data context.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid object name 'DefaultSequence'.

I have no idea where DefaultSequence is coming from.  When the add method is executed I can see it query SQL server something like select next result from DefaultSequence (I don't have that in front of me right now, but something like that was the query that was executed.

Here is the code that I'm using to add the entity and the error is happening on the .Add line:

```
public IActivityCode Create(ActivityCode item)
    {
        data.ActivityCode.Add(item);
        data.SaveChanges();

        return Get(item.Id);
    }
```

Here is the code for the DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<ActivityCode> ActivityCode { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityCode>().ForSqlServer((builder => builder.Table("ActivityCode", "Payments")));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm running a local version of SQL Server 11.0.2100

Comment: I see. Could you try changing `modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityCode>().ForSqlServer((builder => builder.Table("ActivityCode", "Payments")));` to `modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityCode>().ForSqlServer((builder => builder.Table("ActivityCode", "Payments"))).UseIdentity();`?

Comment: If you remove the `ForSqlServer` line, does it still error?

Comment: When I try and add UseIdentity at the end that method doesn't exist.

Comment: If I remove the ForSqlServer line then nothing works because it doesn't know how to map from the Entity to the underlying table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do the below to get this to work.  The comment Jurgen was close, but didn't work as posted, but if you want to post as answer I will accept that as an answer as well.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityCode>().ForSqlServer(builder => builder.Table("ActivityCode", "Payments"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<EquityActivity>().ForSqlServer(builder => builder.Table("EquityActivity", "Equity"));
    modelBuilder.ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();
```